# Setting up quarantine environment on Linux or Mac

Tags: linux, osx-yosemite, c

How can I setup an quarantine environment so that I can test my codes or programs which can fork any number of times? I was trying this on Mac and if I have a fork in a while loop which is not properly bound it makes the terminal freeze and displays fork resource temporarily unavailable. I that case, I can't even use ps or kill and have to turn off everytime I encounter it.

Also, I am trying to kill my child process using _exit(3) - I might be doing this wrong. Can anyone help me with it?

Here is the code I was trying.

```
    pid = fork();
    if(pid > 0){
        if(findCharInString(';',input)){
            printf("Two commands %s\n",input );
            sleep(1);
            _exit(3);
        }
        else{
            system(input);
        }
    }
    if(pid == 0){
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: in linux limit it to 1 or 2 cores with **taskset -c -p 0 34 <myprogram>**  Now it will only use cores 3 & 4 and your whole system should not freeze.

Comment: 'Turn OFF' what - the Mac or the terminal? To be honest WHY would you do this on a Mac? If virtual machines are for a thing this is it.

Comment: You might be able to use the `ulimit` command to limit the max number of processes in your shell, then execute your program (which will inherit the `ulimit` settings), _e.g._: `ulimit -u 20` (to limit  your shell and its descendants to only 20 processes).

Answer (score 0):

pid==0 locks your script in infinite loop, as pid=0 is an equation, but pid==0 is a boolean and always FALSE.

Comment: This has been forked so child process will return its process id and pid of parent will be 0 so once it will not be FALSE when its the parent thread

Comment: I still do not see what can possibly terminate your construct - call me Mr. Slow. _exit() has this bit: "Historically, the implementation-defined process that inherits children whose parents have terminated without waiting on them is called init and has a process ID of 1." Which in turn could make _exit() always return TRUE, but I am not a graduate in this field.